# Power and velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, power

If $P=Fv$, power is constant and the power is the rate of change of kinetic energy, i.e.  $$P = d(mv^2/2)/dt,$$ what must $v(t)$ be to satisfy this equation?

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration under constant power is

$$ a(v) = \frac{P}{m v}$$

Direct integration has

$$ t = \int \frac{1}{a(v)}\,{\rm d} v = \int \frac{m v}{P} \,{\rm d}v = \frac{1}{2} \frac{m}{P} \left( v^2 - v_0^2 \right)   $$

$$ \boxed{ v(t) = \sqrt{v_0^2 + \dfrac{2 P t}{m}} }$$

The verification comes from

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(\frac{1}{2} m v^2) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(\frac{1}{2} m (v_0^2 + \frac{2 P t}{m})) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(P t + \frac{1}{2} m v_0^2) = P$$

Answer (score 0):

$P=d(mv^2/2)/dt=m/2 * d(v^2 )/dt=m/2 * d(v^2 )/dv * dv/dt=m/2 * 2v * dv/dt=mva $

$dP/dt=d/dt * (mva)=m[dv/dt * a+v * da/dt]$

$dv/dt * a+v * da/dt=0$

$dv/dt * a=-v * da/dt$

$dv/(-v)=da/a$

$ln⁡(-v)+C=ln⁡(a)$

$C=ln⁡(a/v)$

$a/v=e^C$

$v=a/e^C $

$v=dv/dt * k$ , where $k=1/e^C$

$dv/v=1/k * dt$

$ln⁡(v/v_0)=1/k * t$

$v=v_0  e^{1/k * t}$

$v=C_1  e^{C_2t}$

Maybe, I broke it down too much, but I think, it's understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The two previous answers are incompatible, so at least one must be wrong. It is easy to see that it's Chanto's. His exponentially increasing velocity implies the same behaviour for the acceleration, $a = \dot{v} = a_0 \, e^{t/k}$ and hence for power, $P(t) = mav = P_0 \, e^{2t/k}$, which clearly isn't constant, contradicting the initial assumption.

The correct answer is given by ja72, which alternatively may be seen as follows:

Newton's equation of motion is $F = ma$. Multiplying by velocity yields power, $mav = Fv = P$. But $mav = m\dot{v}v$ is the time derivative $\dot{T}$ of the kinetic energy, $T = mv^2/2$. So one has the general statement that power $P$ is the rate of change (in time) of kinetic energy, $\dot{T} = P$, irrespective of whether power is constant or not. The kinetic energy is then given by the integral

$$ T(t) = T_0 + \int_0^t dt' P(t') \; .$$

When $P = const$ this becomes $ T(t) = T_0 + Pt$. Plugging in $T$ and $T_0$ as functions of velocities $v$ and $v_0$ and solving for $v$ yields the square root expression given by ja72.